# What is the etymology of the word "anterior"?

Tags: etymology

I am looking for the etymology of the Latin adjective "*anterior*" (which is also a Spanish word, with the same meaning). Neither [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anterior#Latin) nor [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=anterior) provide hints on its etymology. It seems intuitive to me that this word derives from the combination of "*[ante](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ante#Latin)*" and "*[prior](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ante#Latin)*". The latter, in its adjective form is declined in the third declension, just as *anterior* is.

But, is this the etymology of the word? In particular, in which sense would be *anterior* the combination of the meanings of *ante* and *prior*? For what I can see, *anterior* more or less inherited without modification some of the meanings of these words (Wiktionary etymology 1 from [1 of adverb of *ante*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ante#Adverb_2), and etymology 2 from [1 of adjective of *prior*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prior#Adjective_2). But then why a new word?

Comment: Here's another example of a comparative adjective formed from an adverb:  *cis* adverb =on this side; *citerior* adjective =nearer on this side, hithermost.

Comment: @Hugh Citerior apparently comes from [citer](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dciter). *Anterior* is late Latin, according to L&S. Not sure about the technical names of the processes, but maybe the fact it's not classical supports the idea the ending was derived by analogy with postea > poster(us) > posterior, through a non-existent (overcorrected?) *anterus

Comment: @Rafael *Infra* is another interesting form.  Does that spell out the same way?

Comment: Apparently ***infer*** is the Latin for **"Bring it on!"**

Comment: @Hugh for _inferior_ you have the adj. [_inferus_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinferus). I wrote an answer on _anterus_ since I think it was answer worthy with a bit more evidence I found.

Answer (score 5):

I don't find any evidence of *anterior* containing *prior*.  Rather I would guess that *ante* was extended by two suffixes, the contrastive suffix -ter- (also seen in e.g. *alter*), and the regular comparative suffix -ior.

Admittedly, if one just strings the parts together, one obtains **anteterior*, but, I consider a simplification to *anterior* by haplology an obvious development.

Comment: Reinforced, no doubt, by analogy with _posterior_, _interior_, _exterior_.

Answer (score 2):

It is most probably either a regular comparative or one **built by analogy to other regular comparatives**.

Not sure if it is possible to prove or disprove the existence of and adj. **anterus* to which *anterior* would be the comparative, in the same way that *posterior* is of *[posterus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dposterus)*.

*Posterus* is the adj., *postea* the adverb. **Anterus* would be the adj. corresponding to adv. *[antea](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dantea)*.

About the existence of **anterus* and the hypothesis that *anterior* is its regular comparative, I found two pieces of evidence: [a XIX century lexicon by a Latin Professor at Oxford](https://books.google.cl/books?id=k4Dcf4d0N7MC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=anterior%20%22anterus%22&source=bl&ots=X6Dt9E904y&sig=CqgSyoKwZSvb2bKj6kiUg2AaUhE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifvojQopDdAhXFlJAKHavXCO4Q6AEwB3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=anterior%20%22anterus%22&f=false) and [a XV century book](https://books.google.cl/books?id=Hfw-5CNiivwC&pg=RA3-PA9&lpg=RA3-PA9&dq=anterior%20%22anterus%22&source=bl&ots=ECKH2dmMjf&sig=CU87DTbkQXfvg0tWV8pUVjd3bto&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifvojQopDdAhXFlJAKHavXCO4Q6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=anterior%20%22anterus%22&f=false) actually written in Latin by a *[prominent Flemish humanist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Despauterius)* (according to wp).

Now, [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=anterior) says *anterior* is late Latin and cites [Sulpicius Severus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulpicius_Severus) using the word as early as the V century. Whether **anterus* existed or not (at least in spoken) at that time, I haven't been able to find any evidence. The fact that it doesn't show up in good dictionaries or corpora is a good argument against its popularity. But even if it did not exist, the -r- could have been derived (as an innovation) by analogy with postea > posterus > posterior

As noted by Colin and Hugh, the same analogy works with other adverb/adjective pairs:

- infra/inferus/inferior
- intus/internus(?)/interior
- extra/exterus/exterior